# How to get email of account in device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm using an email into my app. Is possible get the email of predeterminate account in iphone with some framework or other method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this isn't possible. You could do one of two things either

1. Let the user enter their own email address into a `UITextField`

or

2. Present the AddressBook to the user using the `AddressBookUI` framework and adding the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate` and let the user pick the email address for a specific contact. Here's some [Apple Documentation for the Address Book Stuff](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH1-SW1)